# PHP IDE compiling code on the fly similar to java

Tags: php, ide, compilation

I got a question about the IDEs: With Java, you use Netbeans or Eclipse, which are very great IDEs to code. Now, if I do a misspelling, Eclipse reports it immediately with a red line (for example a function call which was misspelled).

As I know, this works with some sort of dummy-compiling on the fly.

Now, why is there no IDE at all which provides the same stuff for PHP? Just a sort of "on the fly-interpreting" which does not really execute all functions, but it interprets the code. It would sometimes make programming much easier. Is this possible at all? If no, why not?

Thanks for response ;)

Flo

Comment: Both Netbeans and Eclipse have plugins that support PHP and do exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: At a guess, I would say most likely because much of the Java is client side and PHP is server side, that means a developer would need to constantly have to "submit" the code for lack of a better term while the code executes, then it could be difficult because the PHP likely won't have valid data to use so a number of errors could be generated due to that. Also, without the data it would be difficult to run every scenario that could come about to validate the code. My guess is there is the solution would cause more problems than it would solve.

Comment: @bobwienholt I believe the question is asking why the software only interpret the code and don't actually execute the code... well that's how I read it.

Comment: Client and server side doesn't matter (your script just runs through the interpreter anyway). In dynamic languages things like type errors will only occur at runtime. Which is why you have to unit test your PHP code, no IDE can do that for you automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [PDT Development Tools](http://www.eclipse.org/projects/project.php?id=tools.pdt) plugin for Eclipse does exactly that. Just tell it where your PHP interpreter sits. And keep in mind that it of course can't catch errors that occur at runtime. So it will only report actual syntax errors.

Comment: Well, just as a normal Java error reporter... Ok thanks very much!

Comment: Exactly. Just that the Java one can catch more because of the static typing. Oh and you can simply install it through the update site.